# JSON.NET unable to serialize excel array

Tags: c#, excel, json.net, vba

I am getting an IndexOutOfRangeException when trying to use JSON.NET to serialize and object array retrieved from an excel range.   I think the reason that this is happening is that the excel array is not zero based.

If i create an array like this in .NET, the dimensions would be `{object[4,2]}`

```
object[,] data = {
    { 1111, 1111 },
    { 1112, 1111 },
    { 1113, 1111 },
    { 1114, 1111 },
  };
```

When i look at an array retrieved from Excel however, i see:

```
 {object[1..4, 1..2]}
```

Is this a bug in JSON.Net. I think if i can make the array zero-based, it would work.  but not sure how to do that easily without a maybe creating a new array and copying values one by one.  Any thoughts?

UPDATE:
I tried the following, and looks like this code will do the trick to copy the array starting at index 1 to an array that is zero-based.  Still, i never knew .net arrays can be non-zero based.

```
object[,] zeroBasedArr = new object[oneBasedArr.GetLength(0), oneBasedArr.GetLength(1)];
Array.Copy(oneBasedArr, 1, darr, 0, oneBasedArr.GetLength(0) * oneBasedArr.GetLength(1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting answer in case it helps someone..
Basically i had to make the array zero-based for JSON.Net to be able to properly searilize it:

```
object[,] zeroBasedArr = new object[oneBasedArr.GetLength(0), oneBasedArr.GetLength(1)];
Array.Copy(oneBasedArr, 1, darr, 0, oneBasedArr.GetLength(0) * oneBasedArr.GetLength(1));
```